# Cannot Center Dynamically Added Video

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, storyboard, constraints

So! I layout the storyboard like so:

[image]

...then I dynamically add a video like

```
self.player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: vidURL)!)
self.avpController = AVPlayerViewController()
self.avpController.player = player
self.avpController.view.frame = VidView.frame
self.view.addSubview(avpController.view)
```

HOWEVER! It layouts out not centered like so:

[image]

Comment: In the **viewDidLayoutSubviews** method update the frame of the avpController. Just put this line there **avpController.view.frame = Vidview.bounds**. Remember the bounds here is important.

Comment: where you added following code `self.avpController.view.frame = VidView.frame`?

Comment: if you simply want to layout not caring about flow. So I think if you add `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` at start of above statements then it should work